# change index value in an ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript, loops, ngfor

Good evening, I would like to know if I can change the value of the index of my ngfor by the ID of each item in my list.
since you know the index starts from 0, I would like to know if I can put the value of the id of each element, in the index.

my code is the following:

```
<fieldset *ngFor="let g of grupo; let i = index" [g.id]="i">
```

[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8vYB.png)

Comment: do you want to say `[id]="g.id"`? -if your array of grupo is an array of object, and each object has a property "id"-

Comment: add a picture of my problem to the question

Comment: Kenny, if you has a property "id", write {{g.id}}, g goes to get the values {id:5....},{id:6...}

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to add an `id` to each element in `grupo`. You should do this in the typescript side:

```
for (let i = 0; i < grupo.length; i++) {
  grupo.id = i;
}
```

Something like that.

Comment: each element of the group ngfor already has the id property with its respective value, and I want to replace that value of the id property with the default value that comes in the index que is 0,1,2,3 .....

Comment: Ok, what I show should do that. This should be done in the TypeScript, not the HTML.